# Alter Table Alter Column failing for resizing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ALTER COLUMN COLUMN_NAME
```

Is failing while changing a column from `int` to `bigint` on SQL Server 2005 SP1 (32-bit).

The same is, however, passing on SQL Server 2005 SP1 (64-bit) and SQL Server 2008.

Has anyone experienced this before? Can you point me to the bug raised for this with MS or any article pointing to this?

**Edit:**
The error message is:

> Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.
>   Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: What error - if any - are you getting when it is failing??

Comment: Are there any error messages in logs ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937559%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: The logs have the error message:
Message
Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.

Comment: Do you run DBCC CHECKCATALOG?  Is there any messages in query analyzer?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit surely? Your database is corrupt and you need to run `DBCC CHECKCATALOG` and hope that it can fix the errors.

Comment: When I run DBCC CheckCatalog, it however reports no errors. The same query runs on the same database restored on SQL Server 2005 Express 2005 (SP3), SQL Server 2005 x64 (SP1), SQL Server 2008 (SP2). Unfortunately I have not been able to find a corresponding connect issue for this. Thanks

Comment: Oh I see! The only connect issue I could see at all mentioning `DBCC CHECKCATALOG.` was [this one](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/324261/confirmation-of-bug-given-in-suggestion-id-283124) where apparently the casing of an index name gave this error. Bit of a longshot but are you using exactly the same case in the column name in your `alter column` statement?

Comment: Yes, we are using the same case :( Given that it works fine on SP3 and not on SP1, I guess there's not a lot we can do but upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to SQL Server 2005 SP2 fixes this issue. Apparently there was no bug ever raised for this.

Thanks